# Calling D3 from Ext JS in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, extjs, d3.js

I have the following D3 code which works as expected.

```
``http://jsfiddle.net/6Ldad16n/3/
```

Now, I need to run this from within Ext JS code. So I created another fiddle for this

```
``http://jsfiddle.net/07kk8fzs/
```

I believe there is something else also needed to make it work from within Ext JS, as result displayed is blank and there are no errors in the console.

Can someone please help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: is your ExtJS code working if you don't put d3 code into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not override the `afterRender` method (it is a private method, and thus you should not rely on its existence), but instead put this in your `initComponent` method :

```
this.on('afterrender', function(){
    this.loadScript(this.onD3Loaded, this);
}, this);
```

Your code should work without this modification, but it's a best practice to add your own event listeners instead of overriding the framework's.

Moreover, your code only defined your `d3.widgets.Treeview` class, it does not instantiate it. Try adding this to your code after the `Ext.define`:

```
Ext.create('d3.widgets.Treeview', {
    renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});
```

I tested adding it to your fiddle, but something else throws an error, and I don't know D3 enough to debug it